# Invoking a process via Test Class

Tags: apex, process

In an effort to gain more complete code coverage I've been tasked with writing a test class that verifies that a process (defined in process builder) is run when a record is created or updated in a specific table.  Basically, if a record is created or changed in one table, the process creates or updates a record in a second, custom table.

The process type of the process is "Invokable".

My thought was that if I created the main record, the process would fire, and I could query for the expected results in the custom table (object, whatever).  Sadly no such record is created which means the process never fired.  So now I'm told I have to "Invoke" the process to run after the main table has had a new record created, then check for the desired results in the custom table.

If my process is called "myprocess", what is the syntax to "invoke" or launch the process from the test class?

I'm new to Salesforce and new to Apex, but I am trainable, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Chris

Comment: Invocable Processes are processes called by other processes. So, if your testmethod can ensure that the calling process is triggered and the conditions for entry to the called (invocable) process are met, then it will execute in the testmethod

Answer (score 0):

A process that fires automatically (such as on create of an Account) will fire automatically when running tests IF it is activated in the org. You can't activate it in tests; check that it fires in usual/UI situations.
If this is happening as an error while deploying metadata from a sandbox, then find the setting to deploy processes as active.
Also, change the process name to something more descriptive, but that's not quite relevant here.

TL;DR Active processes fire automatically in Apex tests if they are active, and they can be tested with assertions.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply.  I'm afraid I may have been a little vague/misleading in my original post.  To be clear, I'm referring to an invocable process builder, and not one that is automatically fired on record creation.  I'm wanting to fire an invocable process builder from apex for the purpose of testing since apparently this is required for code coverage.  Under "normal" circumstances the process is fired from Mass Action Scheduler.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.